# Hidden file attributes

Tags: python, attributes

In Python, how do you make a particular file hidden? Or how do you set the file attribute as 'hidden' without using external API's/modules such as WIN32API, etc.

Surely there is something in the standard libraries? As the `os` module does allow to set the "read" and 'write' attributes, it is very strange that there is no mention in the `os` docs of 'hidden'...

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
fn = 'c:\\file.txt'
p = os.popen('attrib +h ' + fn)
t = p.read()
p.close()
```

Comment: Explaining *why* this answers the question would make it a better answer.

Comment: actually I have seen this similar code on the Internet but it did not work, I thought I had made a syntax error so I tried again, but it still does not work

Comment: @ChrisF: this answer shows how to use the standard windows shell command to hide a file (`attrib`). if the OP is looking for a windows specific solution, this answer perfectly matches the question. (unfortunately, the OP did not specify if he is looking for a portable solution or a windows specific one).

Answer (score 2):

Not all operating systems *have* the concept of "hidden" for files, and most (even with all the different versions of Windows 7 etc. there are *still* more forms of *nix out there than Windows) indicate it by having the first character of the filename be a period (`.`). On the OSes that *do* support it you must use some external API or tool in order to set it on the file.

Comment: I know that the use of the initial DOT in front of the file name works for unix/linux OS; but the OS module specifically deals with many other windows specific file attributes. I am just really surprised that the HIDDEN attribute access is/maybe not provided.

Comment: so is there no other alternative other than win32api?

Comment: You could write your own binding with ctypes, but it would still call the same function.